# Letting a non devise_invitable model invite a devise_invitable model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have two models. User and Teacher model. The teacher model should be a devise_invitable model thats invited by the user model which isn't a devise_invitable model. Is it possible for this to happen. E.g. In teacher's model invited_by_id field should be the user_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my User model class, as in user.rb, i added the following line: include DeviseInvitable::Inviter and in the applicationcontroller i added the following method: def authenticate_inviter!    authenticate_user!(:force => true)     end.